# Weird response with Xcode and HTTP request

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I am trying to make an iOS app that communicates with my server through PHP web apps. I have a method in Xcode that will return the text on the website. It works with all the other websites except this one. It works when you open it in a browser but not when the request is sent through the app. (I know there is code that makes the page refresh which could be the cause of the problem but it is every time and never on the browser version) Then it just returns null. Thanks in advance!

PHP File:

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

$key =  mt_rand(100000, 999999);


$sql= "SELECT * FROM sharing_keys
WHERE unique_key LIKE $key";
$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // Change number
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "1";
    header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
} else {
    $add = "INSERT INTO sharing_keys (unique_key)
    VALUES ($key)";

    if ($con->query($add) === TRUE) {
        echo $key;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $add . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
}

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

?>
```

The Xcode method:

```
-(NSString *)getStringFromURL:(NSString *)url {

    NSError *error;
    NSString *stringFromFileAtURL = [[NSString alloc]
                                     initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url]]
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                     error:&error];
    if (stringFromFileAtURL == nil) {
        // an error occurred
        NSLog(@"Error reading file at %@\n%@", url, [error localizedFailureReason]);
    }

    return stringFromFileAtURL;

}
```

Comment: This is a blocking synchronous call.  You should call the asynchronous calls in almost all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
while(true) {
    $key =  mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    $sql= "SELECT * FROM sharing_keys
           WHERE unique_key LIKE $key";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){
        $add = "INSERT INTO sharing_keys (unique_key)
        VALUES ($key)";
        if ($con->query($add) === TRUE) {
            echo $key;
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $add . "<br>" . $con->error;
        }
        break;
    }else {
        //sleep for 2 seconds
        sleep(2);
    } 
}
```

I don't think it is a good idea to refresh in the middle of a request.

This logic will attempt to find the key and exit once found. if not it will sleep for 2 seconds then retry until found.

---

If your only goal was to select a row randomly, then you should do it in the query because only God knows how long it will take. here is an example in mysql server :

```
SELECT * FROM sharing_keys
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Although there is a slight problem. I am much more experienced in Objective C than PHP (as you can probably tell from the original code). I tried running the script you provided and it would never load the page (just time out) and would force me to restart my computer to access anything MySQL. The original intent was just to generate a random 6 digit code and if it doesn't already exist in the table create a row for it and echo the code. Sorry for any confusion!